# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable Python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typeerror

I've been making a small assembler for an assembly language of mine, but it throws an error whenever I try to access a function from a dict.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    command = commands[command[0]]
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

I just found out that you can assign functions to variables, and maybe you can't put them in a dict?
I have tried changing the key name, but it was to no avail. :(
I'm kind of clueless as to why this is happening, if you can store funcs in variables.

```
command = input(f"line#: ").split(",")#this is correct

def ADD(A:float,B:float,R:int):
    Regs[R] = A+B #Regs is an empty array

commands = {
    "ADD": ADD,
}

while (True):
 command = commands[command[0]] #TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: please **always post the full error message including the stack trace**. the python runtime goes to great lengths to provide all that information **precisely because it makes debugging easier**. don't just *omit* that.

Comment: Looking at the code `command = commands[command[0]]` -> first iteration this succeeds but then you rewrite the `command` list with function and it fails.

Comment: ... *and* the input provided.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: There is only 1 iteration.

Comment: @ScottHunter OP probably put the `break` just before pasted the script here. See the solution he posted.

Comment: if code was only executed once the error wouldn't happen, the error occurs for the reason Andrej said

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yup i did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually if this helps, it looks like I was indexing the function!

`diffName = commands[command[0]]`

instead of

`command = commands[command[0]]#Essentially command = ADD;`

fixed it!

This is because, the 1st iteration `command` is the input list,
then is overwritten (`command = ADD`), &
the 2nd iteration tries to do `command = commands[ADD[0]]` and fails because you can't index a function.
(Thank you, comments!)